# Can I add custom editor hints to Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.8

Is it possible to make Netbeans display hints for custom things?

For example I want to display a hint whenever the developer uses the `Date` or the `Calendar` class: "Consider using JodaTime instead of the JDK date classes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this yet, but it should do the trick:
[Netbeans Java Hint Module Tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-java-hint.html)